# Creating a numpy array after a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have this DataFrame:

```
df4=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-05-19'],
                 'A':[153],
                 'B':[139],
                 'C':[165],
                 'D':[165],
                 'E':[123],
                 'F':[135],
                 'G':[137],})

df4['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df4['Date'])
df4 = df4.set_index('Date')
```

Then I transformed df in order to work with numpy

```
row=df4.to_records()[0]

amount = 10000
```

And I created this for loop:

```
for i in np.arange(1,len(row),1):
    test=amount/row[i] if row[i]<=150 else 0
    print(test)
```

This is the result of the variable `test`:

```
0
71.94244604316546
0
0
81.30081300813008
74.07407407407408
72.99270072992701
```

And I would like to know if there is a way to transform all the results of `test` into a numpy array? Hence the result should be something like this :

```
test = [0,71.94244604316546,0,0,81.30081300813008,74.07407407407408,72.99270072992701]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `list` and convert to `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
output = []
for i in np.arange(1,len(row),1):
    test=amount/row[i] if row[i]<=150 else 0
    output.append(test)
np.array(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the list option, you can get the array directly from the iterator:

```
res = np.fromiterator((amount/row[i] if row[i]<=150 else 0 for i in np.arange(1,len(row),1)), dtype=int count=len(row)-1)
```

Note that, since you know how long the iterable is, you can pass the `count` parameter to make it slightly faster (numpy knows how much memory to preallocate and skips resizing as it loops)